# Surjectivity and the non-existence of maps.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, proof-verification

This question comes from Jacobson's Basic Algebra.

It asks:

> Show that $S \overset{\alpha}{\to} T$ is surjective iff there exist no maps $\beta_1,\beta_2$ of $T$ into a set $U$ such that $\beta_1 \neq \beta_2$ but $\beta_1\alpha = \beta_2\alpha$.

I was able to show that surjectivity implies that no such mappings exist, but I'm stuck showing the reverse direction. Intuitively, it makes sense, because if none exist satisfying such criteria, then for any $t \in T$, if there's no $s \in S$ such that $\alpha(s) = t$ then we can define mappings such that $\beta_1(t) \neq \beta_2(t)$, but are otherwise equal. Then of course, $\beta_1\alpha = \beta_2\alpha$, which contradicts the non-existence. I feel like I'm basing my reasoning off of the surjectivity of $\alpha$ rather than the non-existence of the described mappings though, which could possibly be erroneous.

For completeness, I'll write my current progress with the proof below.

Assume $\alpha$ is surjective. If $\beta_1\alpha = \beta_2\alpha$, then considering our maps have the same domains and co-domains, for $\beta_1 \neq \beta_2$, $\beta_1(t) \neq \beta_2(t)$ for some $t \in T$. As $\alpha$ is surjective, for any $t \in T$ there exists $s \in S$ such that $\alpha(s) = t$. However, if $\beta_1(t) \neq \beta_2(t)$ then $\beta_1(\alpha(s)) \neq \beta_2(\alpha(s))$, which contradicts $\beta_1\alpha = \beta_2\alpha$.

Any hints or suggestions? I'm studying independently, so any help or constructive criticism would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the converse, assume that $\alpha\colon S\rightarrow T$ is not surjective. Let $U = \{u_1,u_2\}$ be a two-point set. Define $\beta_1\colon T\rightarrow U$ by $\beta_1(t):= u_1$ for all $t\in T$ and 
$$
\beta_2\colon T\rightarrow U,\quad t\mapsto \begin{cases} u_1 & t\in {\rm im}(\alpha)\\
u_2 & t\in T\setminus{\rm im}(\alpha)\neq\varnothing.\end{cases}
$$
Then we have certainly $\beta_1\circ\alpha = \beta_2\circ\alpha$ but $\beta_1\neq \beta_2$, so these maps do exist if $\alpha$ is not surjective.

Comment: My apologies, I had originally wrote converse but modified my post to say reverse direction. In other words, only half my proof is done. I need to show that the non-existence of such mappings implies surjectivity.

Comment: This is, what I have shown (by contraposition). What I mean sto say is $A\Rightarrow B$ is equivalent to $\neg B\Rightarrow \neg A$.

Comment: Oh, very nice. This makes the proof much simpler.